# Not getting Downloaded - "Azure DocumentDB Data Migration Tool"

Tags: migration, azure-cosmosdb

Here I'm working with Microsoft Azure.
 with in that i'm trying to use the open source DocumentDB data migration tool to import data to Microsoft Azure DocumentDB from various sources, including JSON files, CSV files, SQL, MongoDB, Azure Table storage, and DocumentDB collections. But the problem is "Azure DocumentDB Data Migration Tool" is not getting downloaded onto my system.
In order to download that migration tool, does it require any pre-installation of other softwares onto my system.So can any one please update with some knowledge regarding the issue.Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you downloading from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46436?  You will need to temporarily enable popups for the download to initiate.

Comment: after enable the popups i click on next the its says like "If your download does not start after 30 seconds, Click here"

Comment: If I recall correctly, I ran into same problem with Firefox browser. I ended up using IE and it worked.